# How to convert MySQL master-slave to master-master

Tags: mysql, replication, multi-master

I've searched around, but can't find the exact details to point me in the proper direction.  I currently have 2 MySQL instances under 5.5.41 running as a master-slave setup.  I followed these [directions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql) to set it up.  Since both of these nodes are on the same VM storage I'd like to migrate one to a different datacenter as a master-master config then use JDBC load balancing where the current master is primary and the slave is converted to a secondary master with replication enabled between both.  Can anyone provide the steps I'd need to perform on the MySQL nodes?  I believe I now the correct JDBC line to use for my app connection.

Answer (score 1):

Master-Master has a lot of problems if you are writing to both. It is better to write to only one of them until you need to failover.

Setting up Dual-Master is simply setting up both servers as being both Master and Slave, much like you already did to make your current Master-Slave topology.

Comment: I am also thinking about settings up master-master replication. Could you please list some of the problems?  I know I need to set auto increment properly so there is no conflict in auto incremented numbers.  What else?

Comment: Other sources of duplicate keys.  Split brain.  If something goes wrong; replication stops until you manually fix it.  You don't get write scaling.